# C#, ADO.net. Зависает приложение при попытке подключения к БД

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

Есть код, по нажатию кнопки создаю подключение к базе и делаю запрос.
Данные из которого далее вставляю в listbox. Все работает за исключением того когда база не доступна.

Как усовершенствовать код, чтобы в случае недоступности базы выдавалась ошибка?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                    listBox1.Items.Clear();
                    string ConStr = "Integrated Security = SSPI; Persist Security Info = False; Initial Catalog = stuff; Data Source =(local2)";
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [id], [name], [surname], [fname] FROM [dbo].[current_st]", connection))
                            {
                                using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                                {
                                    while (read.Read())
                                        listBox1.Items.Add(read.GetValue(0) + " " + read.GetString(1) + " " + read.GetString(2) + " " + read.GetString(3));
                                }
                            }
                        connection.Close();
                    }
            }
```

Comment: try {} catch {}

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch

Comment: Спасибо, но в какое место его ставить? Зависает даже с ним.

Comment: Чтобы приложение не зависало, используйте асинхронность. `await connection.OpenAsync();` и т. п.

Comment: Можете уменьшить время ожидания подключения, указав таймаут в строке подключения.